# Grails: use of <g:select>

Tags: grails, populate

I am stuck on something which seems really simple, but apparently is not :) 
Thanks in advances for any help, any attempt of solution is most welcomed.

My problem is the following:
**My .gsp view:**

```
<td> 
   <g:select from="${creditProviders}"/>    
</td>
```

**My .groovy controller method:**

```
def simulate = {// Need to provide the list of credit providers 
        def creditProviders = CreditProvider.findAll()
        [ creditProviders : creditProviders ]
 }
```

**The error I get:**

```
Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:select>: null at /pathTo the view
```

So I do not manage to populate my  tag for some reason...
I can call my ${creditProviders} variable outside the  tag and it works like a charm. 
I am stuck, and do not understand what is wrong.

Wish you a good day :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `<g:select>` probably needs a `name` attribute. Try:

```
<g:select name="something" from="${creditProviders}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you have been runnning into a known issue in grails 1.3.7. You need to define the `name`-tag. If you don't, you get this meaningless NPE. This bug is fixed in grails 2.0 ( http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7656 ).

Good luck ;)